# PHP forked process not exit completely and become zombie

Tags: php, linux

This is a simplified program.

The test.php is a daemon program, always running there.
It forks process to work on some task.
Once finishing work, the forked process exits.
But when the forked process exits, it becomes zombie.

How to make the forked process exit completely without becoming zombie?

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

while (1) {
  sleep(1);

  $pid = pcntl_fork();
  if (!$pid) {
    $mypid = getmypid();  
    sleep(5);
    print "pid=$mypid finish work \n";
    exit();
  }

  sleep(1);
} // while 

?>

./test.php
... daemon running ...

$ ps -ef | grep mqp
ubuntu   10084 10073  0 12:21 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/bin/php ./test.php
ubuntu   10085 10073  0 12:21 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/bin/php ./test.php
ubuntu   10074 10073  0 12:21 pts/0    00:00:00 [test.php] <defunct>
ubuntu   10075 10073  0 12:21 pts/0    00:00:00 [test.php] <defunct>
```

Comment: zombies become such when the parent do not collect the dead child fleshes.

Answer (score 0):

In the parent process you need to call [`pcntl_wait()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-wait.php) or `pcntl_waitpid()` from time to time. These functions wait until a child exits then return its ID and status. The resources used by the child are this way released by the OS and the child does not become a zombie.

The status of the exited child can be used with the `pcntl_wexitstatus()` and other functions from the `pcntl` extension to find out how the child ended its execution (normal termination and an exit code returned, was terminated with ^C, received a signal it didn't handle a.s.o.)